# May Sukkah walls be made of living things?

Tags: sukkah

I'm at a Shiur and the rabbi said that a sukkah can have walls made of anything even "elephants," but I'm pretty sure he was being facetious. Can anyone provide a source verifying or explaining?

Comment: Are you at the shiur right now?  Asking Mi Yodeya about the shiur while you're sitting there?

Comment: @YEZ See his profile pic? ( *in all truth, he's probably using the present tense to describe past events [insert fancy literary term that I cannot remember]* )

Comment: @YEZ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present

Comment: @Shokhet I just thought it was humorous.  Although he mixed up some tenses for historical present.

Comment: @YEZ Don't think so -- if he's thinking back to a point in time at which he remembered something that "the rabbi said" 5 minutes earlier.....וצריך עיון.

Comment: I was in the Shiur then. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a gemara in Succah 23a and halacha rules this way in shulchan aruch orach chaim siman 630 siff 11but it must be tied down so it wont walk away.

> בפיל קשור כולי עלמא לא פליגי דאי נמי מיית יש בנבלתו י
>
> With a tied down elephant, all opinions agree it is kosher, since even if it dies, there are still 10 handsbreadths (of height) left in the corpse

Comment: I was in the middle of quoting it in my own answer, so I might as well just add it in to yours.

Comment: @YEZ That was very nice of you!

Comment: @YEZ ty I was wavering about mentioning the dying part and the space between the legs detail.